# Meaning of "bad timing"

Tags: nouns

What does the phrase "bad timing" actually mean?

I searched for the meaning of it for around 30 minutes before coming to a dead end. It seems like there isn't much info regarding its meaning.

Also I'd like to ask if it's synonymous with "unexpectedly".

Thanks for your responses!

Comment: It's used when the simultaneity of two 'events' (in a very general sense) gives rise to bad consequences. Hitting your golf-ball when a deer suddenly wanders into view and is felled. Telling a joke about a burglar to someone who's just been burgled. Driving at rush-hour.

Comment: It's what the mechanic tells you when you're engine is running rough.  (Hint:  Context needed.)

Answer (score 1):

Something that happens unexpectedly could be either pleasant or unpleasant.

If something happens with bad timing, it comes at a time when it causes the maximum distress or inconvenience. For instance, I had been waiting all summer for a date to move in to my present house. When a date was finally fixed, it was the day I was due to go on holiday! (I packed for the holiday in advance and went a day late, leaving the house to be sorted out when I got back.)